# How does the begining of cluster::pam works?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, package

I'm studying the function *pam* of *cluster* package and something in it seems akward: the function is missing objects. Let me explain what I mean by that.

This is a sample of the function code taken by `cluster::pam` in the terminal.

```
function (x, k, diss = inherits(x, "dist"), metric = "euclidean", 
          medoids = NULL, stand = FALSE, cluster.only = FALSE, do.swap = TRUE, 
          keep.diss = !diss && !cluster.only && n < 100, keep.data = !diss && 
            !cluster.only, pamonce = FALSE, trace.lev = 0) 
{
  stopifnot(length(cluster.only) == 1, length(trace.lev) == 
              1)
  nMax <- 65536
  if ((diss <- as.logical(diss))) {
    if (anyNA(x)) 
      stop("NA values in the dissimilarity matrix not allowed.")
    if (data.class(x) != "dissimilarity") {
      if (!is.null(dim(x))) {
        x <- as.dist(x)
      }
      else {
        if (!is.numeric(x) || is.na(n <- sizeDiss(x))) 
          stop("'x' is not and cannot be converted to class \"dissimilarity\"")
        attr(x, "Size") <- n
      }
      class(x) <- dissiCl
      if (is.null(attr(x, "Metric"))) 
        attr(x, "Metric") <- "unspecified"
    }
    if (keep.data) 
      stop("Cannot keep data when 'x' is a dissimilarity!")
    n <- attr(x, "Size")
    if (n > nMax) 
      stop(gettextf("have %d observations, but not more than %d are allowed", 
                    n, nMax))
    dv <- x[lower.to.upper.tri.inds(n)]
    dv <- c(0, dv)
    storage.mode(dv) <- "double"
    jp <- 1
    mdata <- FALSE
    ndyst <- 0
```

`... it continues`

When running it outside the package by creating my own function in the *Global Env* it accuses that the object *dissiCl* was not created. So, I was wondering why, when running the function as `cluster::pam`, it does not accuse that the object is missing.

You can see this difference by running this two function. The `myPam` is the function created in the *Global Env* by just coping the code from `cluster::pam`.

```
myPam(dist(mtcars), 12)
cluster::pam(dist(mtcars), 12)
```

Also, can someone explain me how could I possibly have this condition, which is in the function code, as *TRUE*: `data.class(x) != "dissimilarity"`.

When inputing `x` as (e.g.) `dist(myBase)`, the class of this object is `diss`. But, how can I create an object of class *dissimilarity*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dissiCl` is a non exported object from the namespace that is attached when you load `cluster`.  The `cluster::pam` function is accessing it. If you want to, use `cluster:::dissiCl` in your function for `dissiCl`.

You're going to run into this problem with other objects in that function as well. If you're trying to run it without running `library(cluster)`. You can just do a find/replace for all of them, adding `cluster::` before each object that is exported, and `cluster:::` for each object that isn't.

You can use the same strategy for converting an object to class `"dissimilarity"`.  If it's already of class `diss`, or if it's of class `"dist"`, I'd suggest using the way the `pam` is coercing it. Just set `class(myBase) <- cluster:::dissiCl`

You may be working with an object that is of class `dist` and not `diss` (`dist()` returns objects of class `dist`), but it looks like that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Is there any way to load objects as `dissiCl` so it would not be mandatory to add the prefix `cluster:::`? Using `library(cluster)` seems to only affect need of namespace operator on functions but not on *variables*

Comment: it's a design decision by the package developer. `library(cluster)` loads exactly those functions and variables the designer decided to export. S/he decided not to export `dissiCl`, so you can only get it with the `:::` operator. There aren't any options in `library` or other methods that will load all the non-exported objects in one shot, so you're stuck with using `:::`